# Bare metal programming: How to access Ethernet HW interface

Tags: networking, ethernet, bare-metal

Bare metal programming: I need to write my own Ethernet driver for the raspberry pi, but I can't find the programmer's hardware manual or other documentation on how to code to the Pi's Ethernet hardware interface. Can some point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: The interface is actually a usb to ethernet chip. I guess you have to implement enough of a usb stack first.

Comment: And then get the data sheet / programming manual for the USB Ethernet chip.

Answer (score 3):

USPi is a bare metal USB driver for the Raspberry Pi written in C. The author has accessed the ethernet controller via internal USB hub

https://github.com/rsta2/uspi/tree/master/sample/ethernet